# What if malloc fails?

Tags: c, memory, malloc

If a `malloc` allocation fails, should we try it again?

In something like this:

```
char* mystrdup(const char *s)  
{
    char *ab = NULL;

    while(ab == NULL) {
        ab=(char*)malloc(strlen(s)+1);  
    }

    strcpy(ab, s);
    return ab;
}
```

Is the while loop valid for checking the memory allocation?

Answer (score 43):

In general, a modern `malloc()` implementation will return `NULL` only as an absolute last resort, and trying again will definitely not help. The only thing that will help is *freeing some memory* and then trying again. If your application holds any expendable resources, this would be the time to free them, and then give it another shot.

In some environments, a useful practice is to allocate a small amount of memory as a *rainy-day fund*. If `malloc()` ever *does* return `NULL`, you can free that rainy-day fund, and then allocate whatever resources you need to be able to handle the error and exit gracefully. This was a common practice when programming with the old Macintosh Toolbox; if `malloc()` returned `NULL`, you could use that space to create a dialog to report the problem before exiting.

Answer (score 10):

In a single-threaded program "trying again" without freeing any memory between tries make no practical sense. It will just loop forever.

In a multi-threaded program this might "work", if another thread running in parallel suddenly decides to free some of its own memory. The loop in such case would constitute a classic "busy waiting" loop. But even in this case such code has very little practical value for more reasons than one.

Comment: It could make sense even in a single-threaded program if the cause of the failure is exhaustion of total memory on the system and not just a per-process limit such as the size of virtual address space or a `setrlimit` limit.

Answer (score 3):

No, never. If `malloc` returns NULL, that indicates an error, and you should probably abort.

Answer (score 3):

Without arguing why or when this would be useful, attempts to reallocate in a loop could work, at least on Windows with 64 bit code, and default pagefile settings. Moreover, this could buy surprisingly more additional virtual memory. Although, do not do this in an infinite loop, but instead use a finite number of retries. As a proof, try the following code that simulates leaking 1 Mb of memory. You have to run it in Release build, preferably not under debugger.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  size_t allocated = 0;
  while (1)
  {
    void* p = malloc(1024 * 1024);
    if (!p)
      break;

    allocated += 1;
  }

  //This prints only after malloc had failed.
  std::cout << "Allocated: " << allocated << " Mb\n";
  //Sleep(1000);
}
```

On my machine with 8 Gb of RAM and system managed pagefile, I get the following output (built with VS2013 for x64 target, tested on Windows 7 Pro):

```
Allocated: 14075 Mb
Allocated: 16 Mb
Allocated: 2392 Mb
Allocated: 3 Mb
Allocated: 2791 Mb
Allocated: 16 Mb
Allocated: 3172 Mb
Allocated: 16 Mb
Allocated: 3651 Mb
Allocated: 15 Mb
```

I don't know exact reason of such behavior, but it seems allocations start failing once the pagefile resizing cannot keep up with requests.
On my machine, pagefile grew from 8 gb to 20 Gb after this loop (drops back to 8 Gb after the program quits).

Comment: A reference that may explain this: Memory allocation errors can be caused by slow page file growth. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4055223/memory-allocation-errors-can-be-caused-by-slow-page-file-growth

Comment: A great answer to a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14181163/2986286

Answer (score 2):

It is incredibly unlikely that this will do what you want; if you're out of memory, busy-looping until you get more is likely to be disappointing. You should just return the NULL to the calling program so that it can deal with resource exhaustion, either by releasing memory it no longer needs or by returning an error.

Answer (score 0):

malloc() tries its best to allocate memory. If it fails, instead of re-trying to allocate memory in a while loop(the program might get stuck there forever), try freeing some memory held by some other process or thread, if you can and then retry.

Another alternative would be increasing memory, by increasing swap file or paging memory, on the fly, from within the code itself(but its dangerous and not preferable) or doing it manually.

Best way to avoid such problems is to calculate or estimate the memory requirement, while writing the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing heap size (memory set aside for dynamic allocation).

Answer (score 0):

**Its depends on what is your sofware for and what part of your code is affected.**

First to know, malloc() can fail when no pages available, if your application reached it's limit then will not work any loop, but if your system ran out of memory it worth a try, but you must avoid any infinte loops. Surprise! Perfectly normal if the operating system temporarily response that could not allocate more RAM, you can handle at your way.

**This is a very good question anyway**

Similar problem is not capturing SIGNALS and when a multi-threaded or async TCP server got an aborted client connection the software terminated by SIGPIPE. This is normal, but leads to end your program however its should not. To prevent this, you have to hook for signals.

In realworld examples (my own).

**When malloc fails and only affect partially of my code**

I used to malloc() or new[] when new connection sending data, Im storing received data into buffers, if malloc or realloc fails, the function return as false and free the buffer, the connection dropped with error (lingerie) so in this case the software continue to run but one connection dropped. I think this is a right way here.

**When malloc must cause software abort**

I used to malloc() to make space for critical data, like arrays, structures that defines the core, this is usually run at the begining of the software as init section, if there is malloc() fail the software must abort and exit with error code, because all operation depending on the tables that must filled with data. (Built-In-Filesystem)

**When malloc able to retry**

I had my datalogger software which is some industry-leading type (High-Availability), if malloc() fails I trigger a mutex_lock() which cause software freeze in backend side and trying to retry the malloc procedure for X seconds. If malloc() continues to fail the software starting to call destructors on all threads and performs a complete shutdown except that thread which is tried to malloc() unsuccessful at this point there are two option, malloc() succeed and finish the stack call and exit the last thread or doing a rollback and exit the last thread.

Whenever is happening the software does not quit as well, try to start from begining and so on..

**Maybe worth to mention ..**

I had exactly the same dilemma years ago, something caused a memory leak in my software and ate all of my RAM but to save the current state I had to write it out which done after many malloc(), the solution was when this happened I closed all threads and calls destructors and saved the data, however the interesting thing was when I closed all connections and free'd up socket, ssl_ctx, ... memory consumption dropped to 128KB, after days of happy debugging I figured it out that SSL_CTX has internal storage and cache. So now when no connection online I free up SSL_CTX and works like a charm.

**SUMM**

So as you can see this is an art, you do what you want with malloc() and anything its just up to you, there is no book and no standard what you should do if malloc() fails. If someone tells you what you should do its just his opinion nothing more.

**my preferred way to avoid infinte loops**

```
PSEUDO CODE:

var ts = TIME()
var max_seconds = 5
var success = true

WHILE (MALLOC() == FAIL) DO
   IF TS + max_seconds < TIME() THEN
      success = false
      BREAK
   END
   SLEEP(100ms)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience (UNIX) it is MOST important to handle malloc failures robustly immediately following a network administrators boast that the "new server you wanted is already out there and ready to go". To which a typical reply is something like: "Wow, that was fast, thanks". Its at THIS point that malloc will return a NULL.

Best thing to do is throw a std::bad_alloc exception with a static error message which gets caught & displayed in main(). Hopefully your destructors do enough cleanup freeing memory that the error processing in main does not fail.

If you use a reasonable OS and programming style, an OOM condition is recoverable.

Comment: "Best thing to do is throw a std::bad_alloc" --> There is no std::bad_alloc exception in C.

Answer (score -1):

You are not properly allocating memory malloc function  require argument as number of bytes it needs to allocated but you are passing the length of the string  so the malloc will reserve memory as per length not per the byte used by your string . You should use sizeof() instead and if still it fails then malloc returns null which represent that there is not enough memory available in the stack to satisfy your requirement.
To run your code properly try this:-

char* mystrdup(const char *s)
{
char *ab = NULL;

```
while(ab == NULL) {
    ab=(char*)malloc(sizeof(s));  
}

strcpy(ab, s);
return ab;
```

}

Comment: I'm afraid you are mistaken: `s` is a pointer to `char`, `sizeof(s)` is the size of a pointer, not the number of bytes required to store the string pointed to by `s`. `strlen(s) + 1` is absolutely correct as `char` has a size of 1 byte by definition, casting to `(char *)` is optional but harmless if `malloc()` was properly declared by including `<stdlib.h>`.