# malloc in do while block

Tags: c, malloc

Can I put malloc in do...while block to ensure successful allocation?

like:

```
#define STR_SIZE 1024 * 1024
char *str;
do
    str = (char *) malloc(STR_SIZE);
while ( !str );
```

Comment: It would be much better to explain what kind of application you are coding.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch ,`typedef struct _LIST LIST, *PLIST;
struct _LIST {
   PLIST pre;
   PLIST next;
};

/* Create a new node */
PLIST node;
do
   node = (PLIST) malloc(sizeof(LIST));
while (!node);
`

Comment: Please edit your question. But this don't describe what *kind* of application you are coding? Is it a server application, which ought to run as long as possible (even with constrained resources), or is it a command line app? Is it some life-critical embedded app (e.g. pacemaker software)?? Why do you want absolutely `malloc` to succeed? Are you aware of the failure modes of `malloc` ??

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch , It's a command line tool.

Comment: Then, you just have to exit with a `perror` on `malloc` failure. No need to ensure successful allocation in that case.

Comment: Related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788803/what-if-malloc-fails

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It probably won't work, because `malloc` rarely fails, it fails when resources are exhausted, and these won't be available soon.

<sup>the only common case when `malloc` could get more resources is if some other big process releases a lot of memory, and that seldom happens and may never happens; if you cared about that add at least a `sleep` in your loop, and be prepared to handle the case when `malloc` genuinely fails and always return `NULL`.</sup>

The better practice is to test `malloc` result and exit with failure and error message, e.g.

```
  char* str = malloc(STR_SIZE);
  if (!str) {
      perror("malloc failed for str");
      exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
```

And every program should deal with the case when `malloc` fails (usually by exiting with an error message).

<sup>A lot of programs call `xmalloc` a function which `exit`-s or `abort`-s when `malloc` fails, and return the allocated zone when it succeeds</sup>

Dealing sensibly with a malloc failure (that is doing something to be able to continue execution) is really hard. Some programs might for instance `free` some other global data. Actually this amounts to implement some specialized [garbage collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) mechanism. Some servers might just fail the current request (and should do that with great care, releasing all the resources used by that current failed request).

And `malloc` can genuinely fail, when you are requiring more resources that those available. So you have to handle that case.

BTW, you could consider using [Boehm's conservative garbage collector](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/) and use `GC_malloc` instead of `malloc` and not caring about its failure and about `free`-ing. (I think that Boehm's GC would abort the program when not enough memory).

Answer (score 2):

As other answers point out, your code is flawed. The idea behind, however, is not entirely unreasonable.

The classic approach for handling `malloc` failure is for the program to exit, as outlined in [Basile's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14180598/1600898). Code that checks the return value of `malloc` is often placed in a generic wrapper function called `xmalloc` or such, and used consistently in place of `malloc`. This is easy to implement and reason about, but it is not without flaws. It makes a lot of sense for short-lived command-line programs such as those typically invoked from a Unix shell, but it fails for interactive programs where it is inappropriate for a program to immediately drop dead, even if it does run out of memory. It is also unsuitable for library code, as the program that uses the library might not want the process to exit merely because a single allocation failed.

Retrying the allocation makes sense when there is a good chance that the memory problem did not result from the activity of your program. For example, a multi-process HTTP server might not want to refuse a request and end the process as soon as a single memory allocation fails. However, a good implementation would: 1) take care to sleep between the requests to avoid busy-looping and give the system a chance to recover, and 2) ensure that the process exits after a number of iterations, in case it is the process itself that is causing the allocation failure. For example:

```
void *safe_malloc(size_t howmuch)
{
  int i = 0;
  while (i++ < 10) {
    void *ptr = malloc(howmuch);
    if (ptr)
      return ptr;
    sleep(i);
  }
  perror("malloc");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

This approach has been used in servers such as the now-obsolete [phttpd](http://development.freecode.com/projects/phttpd) web server.

A different approach to `malloc` failure in interactive applications is the one used by Emacs: a fixed amount of memory is allocated at startup and saved for later. When a memory allocation fails, the relief memory is freed and a Lisp-level exception is raised, abandoning the current operation. A warning message is displayed up to the user explaining the situation. The freed memory enables the program to continue working for long enough for the user to save their work before Emacs goes down.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly, but if `STR_SIZE` is unreasonable this will lock your code forever.

Malloc can also fail on, rare occasions, if your memory is very fragmented. In this case your code will work.

Answer (score -1):

you could, although it's a rarity malloc will fail, syntactically correct but i don't if it's logically correct, ill try to code if it works.